# Python 2.7 strange import warning

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have a weird error re: imports in Python 2.7 when one script calls a different script which calls a different script - `testbench.py` imports `user.py` imports `hardware.py`

- `testbench.py` runs a hardware testbench
- `user.py` takes user input (Specifically, the serial number of the hardware to test)
- `hardware.py` has some information about valid #SNs (In the integer `highestSerial`)
- `user.py` uses the `hardware.highestSerial` variable

In both cases, the workflow is like this:

```
>>>python
>>>import user
>>>help(user)
>>>exit()
>>>python testbench.py
```

**CASE 1**

```
\\testbench.py
\\user.py
\\hardware.py
\\__init__.py
\\hardware\\__init__.py
\\hardware\\hardwareList.txt
```

**Output 1**

- No warnings from help(user)
- Calling the script outputs: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'highestSerial'`

**CASE 2**

```
\\testbench.py
\\user.py
\\hardware.py
\\__init__.py
\\hardware\\hardwareList.txt
```

**Output 2**

- help(user) outputs: `__warningregistry__ = {(Not importing directory 'hardware': missing _...`
- calling the script works fine

**Difference between cases**

In the first case, there is a hardware folder with`__init__.py` in it - there are no warnings, but the code breaks (Because the attribute I'm looking for isn't in the folder)

In the second case, there is no hardware folder so I get a `Not importing directory` warning but the code works fine.

Now obviously I could just rename some things but do any of you know what is going on behind the scenes?

**EDIT** And things go completely crazy when I put hardware.py inside \hardware\ but we'll forget that scenario temporarily

**EDIT 2** My thinking has been that I want to make a hardware.py script to access all the things in the \hardware\ folder - serial number list, hardware types etc., none of which is in python but rather in .txt files, .csv files etc. Is that an entirely mistaken way to do things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have both a hardware *package* and a hardware *module*. Don't. Rename one or the other; Python has to inspect the `hardware` *directory* too.

In case 1, the `hardware/__init__.py` package is being imported before the `hardware.py` module is found, and it appears you left the `__init__.py` file empty, so trying to access `highestSerial` raises an attribute error.

In case 2, the `hardware` directory is inspected for a `__init__.py` file first, raising a warning to let you know that that file is missing; this is to prevent a common error made by beginnning Python developers that forget to create that file.

Python then does find `hardware.py` and imports that instead.

You should not use directory names that match module names. Just rename `hardware.py` (and adjust your imports) or rename the directory.

Comment: @medivh: Because `import hardware` means Python *has* to consider the `hardware` directory, then warning you that a `__init__.py` is needed to be able to do so. The fact you have a `hardware.py` **as well** doesn't change that behaviour.

Comment: It's fine to read text files from a directory, just don't give that directory the same name as the module.

Comment: Indeed; keep that folder of the module search path and it'll not raise the warning either.